# Where not exists in delete

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

A simple issue I'm having. I'm getting a syntax error from the following SQL:

```
DELETE FROM Blog.Category c 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Blog.Posts p
                  WHERE p.postCategory = blog.Category.catId)
```

Obviously I'm missing something silly here. Any hints would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I have also tried

```
DELETE FROM Blog.Category c 
where NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Blog.Posts p WHERE  p.postCategory = c.catId)
```

However I get

`Incorrect syntax near 'c'`

Comment: `blog.Category.catId` seems to be out of place here.... either `blog` is the schema or you aliased it wrong and it should be `c.catId` since that is the alias for the base table

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are missing the alias directly after the `DELETE` statement.

```
DELETE c FROM Blog.Category c 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Blog.Posts p WHERE  p.postCategory = c.catId)
```

---

Alternatively you can omit the alias and use the full table name.

```
DELETE FROM Blog.Category
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Blog.Posts p WHERE  p.postCategory = Blog.Category.catId)
```

Answer (score 4):

I like updating and deleting alias'd tables better as I feel it is more clear.

```
DELETE c
FROM Blog.Category c
left join Blog.Posts p ON p.postCategory = c.catId
WHERE p.postCategory IS NULL
```

The issue in your query is you alias the table and then don't use it in the EXISTS.

Comment: Joins are faster? I feel like that requires a bit of proof as that is not usually the case afaik

Comment: @JoePhillips In small datasets, it's negligible. I just created a small example with 50,000 and 100,000 records in two table and ran them alternating 10 times. The JOIN averaged 3ms and the NOT EXISTS averaged 7.5ms.

Comment: I think you might get different results if you use wider tables

Comment: @JoePhillips Working on loading up a dataset 100 times my original size now. Just waiting on it to finish :)

Comment: Removed the part about joins being faster. I was likely thinking of sub-selects. Subsequent testing at 5mil and 10mil table sizes showed the if exists were about 60% the time of a join.

Comment: I'm just impressed you actually went and tested it :D

Answer (score 2):

Same topic here

> In SQL Server, when using not exists, you need to set an alias for the table to be connected, and in the delete statement, to specify the table to delete rows from.

[Trying to delete when not exists is not working. Multiple columns in primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803023/trying-to-delete-when-not-exists-is-not-working-multiple-columns-in-primary-key)

Comment: I voted to close the other question

Answer (score 1):

Try this following query, I think it is related to alias:

```
DELETE FROM Blog.Category c 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Blog.Posts p
                  WHERE p.postCategory = c.catId);
```